# Hypothesis Testing with t value

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to solve this problem and I have deduced that it is a two tail test with $H_0: \mu = 4.5$  and $H_a: \mu \ne 4.5.$ But I am stumped on how to find n since it is needed to find the test statistic... Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

A personnel manager reads in a national newspaper that the average office worker wastes 4.5 hours per week by arriving late, socializing, conducting personal business, working slow, faking illness, taking long lunch hours, and sleeping on the job. By observing his officer staff, he obtains a random sample for a hypothesis test because he believes that his staff is different. The average time waster per week for 10 weeks was 4.1 hours with a standard deviation of 1.33 hours. If a hypothesis test was performed at the .01 level with an assumption of a normally distributed population, the test statistic and p-values are:

Comment: I have put your first paragraph into proper notation for easier reading. Please check that the meaning is correct. But I'm puzzled by the 2nd paragraph: Average time 'waster' or 'wasted'? If the latter, do you suppose replications are $n = 10$ _days_, not individual employees?

Answer (score 1):

If the conjecture in my comment is correct, then $\bar X = 4.1,\, S = 1.33,\,
T = \frac{4.1 - 4.5}{1.33/\sqrt{10}},$ and so on. Here the $n = 10$ observations are weekly averages of time wasted.

If you believe this formulation is correct and still don't see the answer, you can show your conclusion to reject $H_0$ or not at the 1% level, along with your reasons. I (or someone else) should be able to take a look to see if you are right.